# Lightningchart JS Bug Report: Dashboard Trading Example, part of the Bollinger Band vanishes

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

This bug applies to this particular Lightningchart JS example found [here](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0502-dashboardTrading.html).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to line 134 of the provided source code.
2. Replace lines 134 to 136 with the code below. This code simply generates 30 days' worth of OHLC data in 15 min intervals.

   ```
   createOHLCGenerator()
       .setNumberOfPoints(2880)
       .setDataFrequency(15 * 60 * 1000)
   ```
3. After the charts reload, zoom in on the right side of the candlestick chart.
4. Then zoom out. Part of the Bollinger Band should now be cut off and invisible.

This bug was reproduced on these browsers so far:

- Firefox version 84.0
- Chrome version 87.0.4280.88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and it's going to be fixed in a future release.
The issue comes from inconsistent default value for series max point count, which defines how much data is kept for visualisation. All other series have the max point count set to `0` which means the feature is disabled.

As a workaround you can call `setMaxPointCount(0)` on the area series.

```js
areaRange.setMaxPointCount(0)
```

In future bug reports should be send as email to `support@arction.com` instead of being posted to StackOverflow.

Disclosure: I'm lead software architect for the LightningChart JS product.